# Google plus authentication on Google App Engine Python Example

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus

I read tons of documentations, but I cannot find e real full-working example of a Python Google App Engine that simply gives a Login/Logout button to the GOOGLE PLUS authentication system.

Probably this is due to my limited understanding.

My need is to use the info on the backend side in order to give customized contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because apparently Google+ Sign-In is being phased out, replaced by Google Sign-In: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide.

If you're just starting it's probably better to go directly to the newer method (or maybe check if other alternatives might be available/better fitted for your app: https://developers.google.com/identity/) then re-focus your searches accordingly.

Also **very important** (for most if not all newer authentication methods) - pay attention to the implementation guides:

- no code example will be **working out of the box** as various application-specific service configurations are usually needed as well
- no code example will be **complete** since it needs to incorporate application-specific keys or other pieces of info that can only be obtained from the above service configurations

Comment: Thank you Dan, your suppor was precious. At the end, i used a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved the problem using simpleauth.

https://simpleauth.appspot.com/

Surely the easyest and efficient way to add oauth2 authentication in your website.